Keycloak - handling dynamic groups assignment
My solution consists of 3 main components:

Keycloak acting as IdP with open-id and OAuth2
Angular front-end application. Stateful, supports authentication.
Backend Java application. Stateless, supports authorization.

Keycloak user-group-role structure looks as follows:

Description of the Keycloak setup:

The User is assigned to the Company 1 through the means of direct assignment to Keycloak child groups
Realm roles are assigned to Keycloak Child groups. With that the User receives his roles.
The user is never assigned to the Company (Keycloak main group) directly
Requirement until now: User may belong to multiple group-role (Keycloak child groups) but only 1 single Company (indirectly through child groups).
The user may not belong to more than 1 Company. In here, he is assigned to Company 1; if Keycloak Admin would assign him to Company 2, the application would throw the exception
Application relies on the information in the access_token through custom claim in the token: " company": "Company 1"

We have now a new requirement:

The User may belong to more than 1 Company
In the above scenario he may be assigned to Company 1 and Company 2 at the same time

Questions:

What are the best practices to satisfy the new requirement?


With the current setup, custom claim in access_token looks like that: "company": ["Company 1", "Company 2"] when the User would be assigned to Company 1 and Company 2. That breaks the app because the User should work within context of just one Company at any single point in time.

There should be 2 places/moments where the User chooses for which company he wants to work at any moment in time: during logging and during application runtime.

I thought about adding an additional claim to the access_token, eg. "current_company": "Company 2", which would reflect the company chosen in the front-end app. This information then could be used by the back-end app. However, is it a good idea ? If so, how to achieve that ? How to pass values dynamically to the access_token from the app ?

Having just "current_company" claim (assuming dynamic token claim value update is a good idea) itself would not be enough I believe. It would have to be combined with the roles assigned to the User too.



Is the current Keycloak user-group-role setup the optimal one ? Are there any better practices ?

